# How does one establish SIGRTMIN at run-time?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, signals

Reading up on `signal(7)` I can see that now: two, but once: three; signal numbers past 31 are reserved for use by the Real-time signal system and should not be used:

> Real-time Signals
>
> Linux supports real-time signals as originally defined in the POSIX.1b real-time extensions (and now included in POSIX.1-2001). The range of supported real-time signals is defined by the macros `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX`.  POSIX.1-2001 requires that an implementation support at least `POSIX_RTSIG_MAX(8)` real-time signals.
>
> The Linux kernel supports a range of 32 different real-time signals, numbered 33 to 64. However, the `glibc` POSIX threads implementation internally uses two (for NPTL) or three (for LinuxThreads) real-time signals (see `pthreads(7)`), and adjusts the value of `SIGRTMIN` suitably (to 34 or 35). Because the range of available real-time signals varies according to the `glibc` threading implementation (and this variation can occur at run time according to the available kernel and glibc), and indeed the range of real-time signals varies across UNIX systems, programs should **never refer to real-time signals using hard-coded numbers**, but instead should always refer to real-time signals using the notation `SIGRTMIN+n`, and include suitable (run-time) checks that `SIGRTMIN+n` does not exceed `SIGRTMAX`.

So, how do I determine the value (in a C program that needs to set up signal handling for itself and any children) of SIGRTMIN when the program is running?  I have looked through questions and answers here but they all seem to treat `SIGRTMIN` as if it was a `#define SIGRTMIN 34` when the `man` page says that should not be done!

Comment: I would discuss these concerns with the author of any package you saw using hard coded constants instead of using the defined macros.

Comment: Ah, so it *is* a MACRO with a run-time value is it? Not a compile constant!  Right I'll take a deeper look and see where it is....

Comment: asm-generic/signal.h:#define SIGRTMIN 32
signal.h:extern int __libc_current_sigrtmin (void) __THROW;
x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/signum.h:#define SIGRTMIN        (__libc_current_sigrtmin ())
x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/signum.h:#define __SIGRTMIN 32
x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/signal.h:#define SIGRTMIN 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupidly I had forgotten that things that are `#define`d are not constant unless they are written that way!

As @RuiFRibeiro points out in the `/usr/include/`*architecture-specific*`/bits/signum.h` include file at the bottom is the pair of MACROS that provides what is needed:

```
#define SIGUNUSED   31

#define _NSIG       65  /* Biggest signal number + 1  
                   (including real-time signals).  */

#define SIGRTMIN        (__libc_current_sigrtmin ())  
#define SIGRTMAX        (__libc_current_sigrtmax ())  

/* These are the hard limits of the kernel.  These values should not be
   used directly at user level.  */
#define __SIGRTMIN  32  
#define __SIGRTMAX  (_NSIG - 1)
```

So now I know how to prevent signal handlers from being attempted to be replaced for those reserved one - I suspect any attempt would be rejected anyway but for error reporting it is better to know what the limits are rather than to determine them from a suck it and see approach!